# Is there a way to fetch videos posted by a channel before or after a certain date with YouTube API?

Tags: node.js, axios, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

What I am trying to accomplish is make an API request that returns X videos published by a YouTube channel before or after a certain date that I specify, for example if a video was published on 04/09/2023 I want to get the data of the 200 videos posted on that channel after that date, or before that date.

Comment: You're looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint with [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) filter and [`publishedBefore`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedBefore) and [`publishedAfter`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter) fields.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Thanks alot! Can you post the answer so that I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint with [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) filter and [`publishedBefore`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedBefore) and [`publishedAfter`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter) fields.